# Convert 837 I&P 4010 (Paper/Proprietary) to 5010 format

Tags: edi

I am having 4010 (Paper/Proprietary) file in X12 format. Now i have to convert this X12 file to 5010 X12 file.
Please let me know a way to do it. Is there some tool or website which can help me achieving it.

Thanks,
Abhishek Garg

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have already tried using a tool OTTS and also i have checked all the posts but couldn't find anything. I can make it work but I have to refer to a data map and then make the 5010 file manually. So i am looking for a solution which can take 4010 file input and give a 5010 file as output

Comment: Any universal data translator (commercial package) can do this.  Or you can write your own code to parse the 4010 version and generate the 5010 version.  It's just text, and you should have the guidelines for both.

Comment: somebody did this using bots (http://bots.sourceforge.net). It is quite easy, thinks there is a plugin for 837 that an user made. What I am not sure if result is 100% correct - one would have to check this thourougly.